# How to open a specific screen of React Native app when a link is clicked from browser?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, deep-linking, react-native-navigation

I created a React Native app with Expo. How do I open a specific screen of the app when the user clicks upon a link like below:

```
https://staging.wapal.com/reset/password?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImJhc2lycnBheWVuZGFAZ21hSI6InBhc3N3b3JkUmVzZXQiLC12J1c2VyX2lkIjoxOTYsImlhdCI6MTYyNzQ4ODM1OSwiZXhwIjoxNjI3ND3123kxOTU5fQ.LZZvXNnlsLMEB4YWwojRvbiz8PPwRMq1QQPyJZrakls
```

Based on my research, I installed `expo-linking` and in `MainStack.js`, I configured it as follow:

```
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";

const prefix = Linking.makeUrl("/");

const linking = {
  prefixes: [prefix],
  screens: {
    ResetPassword: "Resetpassword",
  },
};


// ... 

<NavigationContainer linking={linking}> 

// ...
```

There're probably certain parts that I didn't understand from the doc and not getting the expected result. How do I solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, how were you able to achieve it?